# How to use Flinks Splitter Methods in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

The flink documentation has an example for the usage of the Splitter methods in scala which goes like this:

```
// Create an Array of K TrainTestDataSets
val dataKFolded: Array[TrainTestDataSet] =  Splitter.kFoldSplit(data, 10)
```

In Java however I am forced to pass to further arguments for `TypeInformation` and `ClassTag`. I think for the `TypeInformation` the `TypeInformation.of(TypeofDataset.class)` is the valid input. But I cannot find out what to use for the second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this Scala signature

```
def kFoldSplit[T: TypeInformation : ClassTag](
      input: DataSet[T],
      kFolds: Int,
      seed: Long = Utils.RNG.nextLong()
) : Array[TrainTestDataSet[T]]
```

The Java call would be

```
Splitter.kFoldSplit(
    data,
    10,
    99,
    TypeInformation.of(TypeofDataset.class),
    ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(TypeofDataset.class)
)
```

`ClassTag$` comes from

```
scala.reflect.ClassTag$
```

---

Horrible, but necessary.